# why get sub-array from $arr =jQuery.makeArray() is string type?

Tags: jquery, json

1. I assigned php value into JS variable by jQuery.parseJSON.
2. After that, Converting an array-like object(i.e. cars) into a true JavaScript array(i.e. carsArr) by jQuery.makeArray().
3. Then I want to get the 1st array(i.e.carsArr[0])of carsArr variable which should be array type as well.

However, the alertbox shows it'string type.

So how can i get the 1st array of carsArr variable? Thanks!

```
<?php
    $car1=array("Saab","Volvo","BMW");
        $car2=array("123","234","345");

        $cars = array($car1, $car2);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var cars =jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($cars); ?>');

        var carsArr =jQuery.makeArray(cars);

    var aCar = carsArr[0];

    alert(typeof(aCar));

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are doing javascript like variable assignment in PHP

Change `$cars = array(car1, car2);`

To `$cars = array($car1, $car2);`